# Car struggles to start when warm (fine when cold)

Tags: starting, ignition, golf, distributor

Car is a Mk1 Golf Cabriolet with JH1 injected engine.

The car struggles to catch when the engine is warm. It turns over easily but will start to fire on only 1 or 2 cylinders for a while before catching on all 4. When cold, there is no problem - it starts normally. When running, either hot or cold, the car drives normally.

I have replaced the plugs, leads and battery, but no change. I have also replaced the fuel filter, thinking there was a blockage, but again no change.

The distributor cap and rotor seem a little worn and there is carbon deposits that I scrape off sometimes. Could that be a cause?

Comment: Does the engine run rough when warm, or do you have any performance problems?

Comment: No, once running engine seems smooth. However, it does feel a little down on power when warm. I think it may need timing adjusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that for whatever reason ensuring the lifter pump seal was properly fitted fixed this. I ended up using aviation gasket sealant along with the O ring.